# Will additional ascorbic acid preserve hemp milk for a longer duration?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, biochemistry

Ascorbic acid is known as a natural preservative and many food manufacturers add it to their food to prolong its shelf life.

Hemp milk is a drink that is created by blending 1 part hemp seeds with 2/3 parts water at a high speed. Usually, hemp milk will stay fresh if refrigerated for about 4-5 days.

Hemp seeds naturally contain ascorbic acid. However, how much additional ascorbic acid is required to extend the shelf-life of refrigerated hemp milk by a given amount of days?

For example, to extend the shelf-life for an extra 5 days.